# Is it possible to use isin() and wildcard searches together in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a dataframe that I want to filter rows based on a list of conditions.This seems to work if I know the exact values - using `.isin()` - but when I want to use a wildcard - similar to the `.like('%condition%')` - the filtering does not seem to work. Does anyone know if this is possible? Otherwise I will have to loop through the conditions and add a like filter for each. I have tried both with and without * on the list of conditions to unpack it:

```
filter_out_conditions=['condition_1', 'condition_2']
df.where(~col(check_col).isin(*filter_out_conditions))
df.where(~col(check_col).isin(filter_out_conditions))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the condition as per requirement

```
cons = ['%1%','%3%']

cod = ' or '.join([f"col1 like '{i}'" for i in cons])

df.filter(cod)
```